# Two fragments refactoring into one

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created two fragments: 'scheduleFragment' and 'clockFragment'. After setting up

```
public class ClockFragment extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private int notificationId = 1;
```

in MainActivity.java, the pageAdapter

```
        scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
    clockFragment = new ClockFragment();

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(clockFragment, "Clock");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(scheduleFragment, "Schedule");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

creates an error that states I have to switch refactor the clockFragment into the scheduleFragment so one fragment is created.

I need these two fragments because, in the ClockFragment (tab), the clock must appear to users and on the ScheduleFragment (tab), the schedule of users is present. I am not sure how I can separate the two tabs without causing an error.

Some explanation over why this error occurs and a solution will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

private ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment;
private ClockFragment clockFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
    clockFragment = new ClockFragment();

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alarm_24);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_assignment_turned_in_24);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    public void addFragment(ClockFragment fragment, String title) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitle.add(title);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitle.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hmmm... **`ClockFragment extends AppCompatActivity`**, maybe that's part of the problem don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

First ClockFragment extends Activity which means it is not a fragment.

I will give you an example of how you should do things:

```
public class ChildFragment1 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_fragment_1_layout, container, false);
    Button buttonInFragment1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    buttonInFragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button in fragment 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Now do Fragment 2:

```
public class ChildFragment2 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_fragment_1_layout, container, false);
    Button buttonInFragment1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    buttonInFragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button in fragment 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Now add a new class for the adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return new ChildFragment1(); //ChildFragment1 at position 0
        case 1:
            return new ChildFragment2(); //ChildFragment2 at position 1

    }
    return null; //does not happen
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2; //three fragments
}
}
```

And your MainActivity would look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What is the purpose of the Button buttonInFragment1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1)?

Comment: it is just an indicator. A button in the view itself. you can put any UI element you desire. This is just an example to get you familiarized on how to use fragments.

Comment: I get it now. Can you explain why viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(clockFragment, "Clock");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(scheduleFragment, "Schedule"); does not work? The error comes up as 'incompatible types: ClockFragment cannot be converted to ScheduleFragment'

Comment: I will have to see the adapter class but anyways this is not the best practice. I suggest you follow this example.

Comment: Okay. I tried running your example in my code but the app keeps crashing. I am not sure what the problem is. I have added the MainActivity's code in the post.

Comment: you did not implement the example as is

Comment: Okay, sorry. I just wanted to see if it could work that way. I tried to run the program using your example but, it did not work (with no specific error - just opens and closes).

Comment: do you have the layouts right? It can't open and close without an error

Comment: I will make a new project and try.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried the code in a new project and it opens and closes for some reason. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: can you take screenshots of the code or show the log? this shouldn't happen at all

Comment: https://cf-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/fernandesk1_cardiff_ac_uk/EjOWqUT56mtHuf4EYDOyS90BfXIDfXCDByRDWJnEgkj_ZQ?e=bwY3qh

Comment: I have linked you to my sharepoint account where you can access the project folder.

Comment: Thank you for your help, by the way. Not many people on stack really help someone for this long.

Comment: You are welcome. I will check it and get back to you